# how to hide url vlue with php

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I have a js code in which i want to hide the actual url and show a md5 hash with my domain if any one try to copy the source he will get the invalid destination so the script can only work on my domain

here is the js code i have

```
<script>
jwplayer("container").setup({
    width:640,
    height:360,
    stretching:"exactfit",
    primary: "HLS",
    autostart:true,
    image: "http://url-of-image",
    file: "http://url-of-file"
});
</script>
```

so i want to hide both **url-of-image** and **url-of-file**

Comment: instead of showing `image: "http://url-of-image",
    file: "http://url-of-file"` i want it to show as `image: "md5-hash-here",
    file: "md5-hash-second-here"`

Comment: yes i want to hide in source code

Comment: but if someone will check the source file he can easily reach to that xml file isn't it

Comment: i tested it but still reachable to the main one easily

Comment: XML's are reachable just like HTML's.
The offered method isn't answering your demands.

Comment: URLs don't work like that. If you create a URL with an MD5 in it that you can use to access a resource, then you've just created a different URL that can be copied.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide the URL, because it will be visible to the end user at final stage. You better set a cookie on your page and when delivering video or any file check if cookie exists. [Here](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php?page=all) you can find an example:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !example-cookie=true
RewriteRule .* /err/401.php
```